# Mapping function argument value to an action

Tags: python, function, mapping, aiohttp

So in my current project i am using aiohttp and aysncio for the first time and slowly getting my head around it, this question isn't specifically about the use of these though. I have a function that sends requests, and it has a parameter reqType, which defaults to get but can be any of the 6 request methods aiohttp supports. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to map that value to the sending of the request, other than writing a bunch of small functions and using a dict to map the value to the function.
I tried something like this:

```
{
'PUT': async with session.put(path, data = data, headers = headers) as resp,
'POST': async with session.post(path, data = data, headers = headers) as resp,
'GET': async with session.get(path, params = data, headers = headers) as resp,
'PATCH': async with session.patch(path, data = data, headers = headers) as resp,
'DELETE': async with session.delete(path, headers = headers) as resp,
}
```

but this is not valid code, and i didnt suspect it would work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use `async with session.request(verb, ...) as resp`

See http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_reference.html#basic-api